# how to assign values to numpy array given the row indices and starting column indices?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

```
a = np.array([2,3,1,4])
b = np.array([2,3,7,1])
c = np.zeros((4, 10))
```

I wanna assign value `1` to some elements in `c`. `a` and `b` define the positions of such elements. `a` is the starting column indices of value `1` in each row.  And `b` represents how many consecutive `1` there are in the row. The output I am expecting is:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I can use a simple for loop as below:

```
for i in range(c.shape[0]):
    for k in range(a[i], a[i]+b[i]):
        c[i,k]=1
```

But it would be slow for large arrays, is there any faster numpy indexing to do this? Thanks.

Comment: `c[i, a[i]:a[i]+b[i]] = 1`  should work instead of the `k` loop.

Comment: yes, my main concern is the outmost for loop.

Comment: You can't tackle the outer loop without first dealing with the inner.

Comment: What's the typical shape of c with your actual use-case?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it into a 1D problem

```
def convert_inds(a,b,array_shape):
    
    nrows,ncols = array_shape
    to_take = np.zeros(sum(b))
    count = 0
    for ind,item in enumerate(b):
        start_ind = ind*ncols+a[ind]
        to_take[count:count+item] = np.arange(start_ind,start_ind+item)
        count += item
        
    return to_take.astype(np.int)

to_take = convert_inds(a,b,c.shape)

c.ravel()[to_take] = 1
```

In the code above, `convert_inds` will convert `a` and `b` to

```
array([ 2,  3, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 34])
```

which are indices of `1`s in the flattened `c`. By doing this, you only need to iterate through `b` in the function `convert_inds`.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented next solution without any Python loops, just pure NumPy code. Maybe it is not that simple as python-loop solution, but definitely will be much faster especially for large data.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDbjoMgEIbveYq5hC01pTW7ick@iSHNqGxrokgAG92Xd0ese8hyw/D9/HNyc7wP9rIsbe8GH8GOvZsBA1jHWGM@IJh4fWB3PTccJVAkIUT0MUjojA2iYECnMrcA708FDuTO0KO9GY5ZuKMz5UkLeIH9pXSyGdustuQ@pHwJ12tEfL2yeuzD2HORlHYiTMkHawLn6V95VFoKCU2cndnU1sbXfDdQ5WcJina2OQuyfouq0HBMHSVO/aifku30tw/MPD5Mx0XZTmsG2gtjuFVH73Hm5VlepJK5Fqz6x9@kIl5v/NP4gYbJJaiTEIz92nhNTALtvRLMeRqL12JZvgA)

```
import numpy as np

def set_val_2d(a, val, starts, lens):
    begs = starts + np.arange(a.shape[0]) * a.shape[1]
    ends = begs + lens
    clens = lens.cumsum()
    ix = np.ones((clens[-1],), dtype = np.int64)
    ix[0] = begs[0]
    ix[clens[:-1]] = begs[1:] - ends[:-1] + 1
    ix = ix.cumsum()
    a.ravel()[ix] = val

a = np.array([2,3,1,4])
b = np.array([2,3,7,1])
c = np.zeros((4, 10))

set_val_2d(c, 1, a, b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you choose a fancy indexing based approach, the most difficult part is finding indexes of axis 1. This is very similar to:

```
>>> np.repeat(a, b)
array([2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4])
```

except that each groups of indexes should be incrementing. This fix can be done with this function:

```
def accumulative_count(counts, initial):
    counter = np.ones(np.sum(counts), dtype=int)
    marker_idx = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(counts)[:-1]]
    subtract_vals = np.r_[1, counts[:-1]]
    initial_vals = np.r_[initial[0], np.diff(initial)]
    counter[marker_idx] = counter[marker_idx] - subtract_vals + initial_vals
    return np.cumsum(counter)

>>> accumulative_count(counts, initial)
array([2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4], dtype=int32)
```

After all, you're capable to finish it:

```
c[np.repeat(np.arange(len(c)), b), accumulative_count(b, a)] = 1
```

`c:`

```
array([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```